# Server response is empty in express nodejs web service

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Hi I am working on express rest webservice. I am calling one url using `request-promise` and I want to process response and return to the client.

But I see that it always returns empty response. What I am doing in promise? I debugged response of calling webservice using `rp` which is returning a response well.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var rp = require("request-promise");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const { rollbar } = require("../config/rollbar");
const { baseUrl } = require("../config/settings");

/** API to get all currency price */
router.get("/:ticker?", function(req, res, next) {
  var currencyList = [];

  // it can be null as ticker is optional parameter
  let reqCurrencyName = req.params.ticker;

  const promise = Promise.resolve(
    rp(baseUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      // if no error and http response code is 200
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $("tr").each(function name(i, elem) {
          // currency name
          var currencyName = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(1)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim();

          // market cap value
          var marketCap = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(2)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim();

          // currency price
          var price = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(3)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim();

          // date supply value
          var dataSupply = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(4)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim()
            .replace(/ /g, "");

          // volume value
          var volume = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(5)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim();

          // negative change value
          var negativeChange = $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(6)
            .text()
            .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            .trim();

          // first item is empty in response so lets not push it into an array
          if (currencyName !== "") {
            if (reqCurrencyName !== undefined) {
              if (currencyName === reqCurrencyName) {
                const currencyItem = {
                  currencyName: currencyName,
                  marketCap: marketCap,
                  price: price,
                  dataSupply: dataSupply,
                  volume: volume,
                  negativeChange: negativeChange
                };

                currencyList.push(currencyItem);
              }
            } else {
              const currencyItem = {
                currencyName: currencyName,
                marketCap: marketCap,
                price: price,
                dataSupply: dataSupply,
                volume: volume,
                negativeChange: negativeChange
              };

              currencyList.push(currencyItem);
            }
          }
        });
      } else rollbar.rollbar.l(error);
    })
  );

  Promise.all(promise).then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request-promise` returns a promise, you shouldn't use callback to get the result of async call. You shouldn't create a fulfilled promise with `Promise.resolve`, instead of this you need to create a promise chain from `rp` and use `then` callback to get result and `catch` callback to handle possible errors.

And you execute only one async operation, `Promise.all` don't needed there.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var rp = require("request-promise");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const { rollbar } = require("../config/rollbar");
const { baseUrl } = require("../config/settings");

/** API to get all currency price */
router.get("/:ticker?", (req, res, next) => {
  var currencyList = [];

  // it can be null as ticker is optional parameter
  let reqCurrencyName = req.params.ticker;

  rp(baseUrl)
    .then(body => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      // Ppocessing...
    })
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(err => {
      rollbar.rollbar.l(err);
      res.send({ error: err })
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Btw, `request-promise` throws error if response status is not 2xx, by default. So you shouldn't validate response status in your code.

Comment: where I should use `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.all` ?

Comment: You should use `Promise.all` when you want to wait for more than one promise to complete. `Promise.resolve` is useful when you want to create a promise chain, and the first running function in a chain is not asynchronous (for example validation function, which can throws errors).

Comment: Okay. so here it is already creating a promise chain for me right ?

Comment: In my example, `rp(baseUrl)` creates a promise chain.

Comment: Ah I see. I am getting GET /ticker 304 6798.232 ms - -

Comment: The code on pastbin is incorrect, compare it with code in my answer.